# Is it healthy to fast for a full day once a week?

Tags: digestion, benefits, fasting, frequency, detox-purge

I heard that fasting once a week gives some rest to our digestive system
and allows it to refresh. I tried this twice, but it gave me a headache and made me feel uneasy. Is it good for health?

Will it helpful to body?

Comment: Did you search this site for the word "fasting" before asking this question?  I'm guessing the answer is no.

Comment: A similar question has been answered [here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/9384/are-water-only-fasts-healthy-can-they-cause-headaches-or-other-medical-problems). Studies do not provide convincing evidence of physical health benefits or harms of fasting, but it is known that occasional fasting can help someone achieve the peace of mind. For an unexperienced person, fast can be stresfull and hence associated with symptoms as you've described, but this does not mean it's not healthy. It may be good to discuss such things face to face with and experienced person.

Comment: I have tried it. It works alright, if you gradually cut down your caffeine intake to about zero before you start your one day fast. It suits Saturdays best. However, it gets boring to do in the long run. To make it less tedious one can alternate with a half Saturday's fast every now and then, skipping breakfast and just have lunch and dinner.